# can I back out after signing a mortgage loan disclosure?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, home-loan

Can I change to another lender after signing a mortgage loan disclosure?

I'm a first-time home buyer, not refinance.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you specifying the disclosure statement that you receive prior to doing anything on the loan (ie, prior to the appraisal, inspection, etc.)?  Or the HUD-1 that you receive at closing?

Comment: @Joe yes, the inspection and signing disclosure were both done on yesterday, but I haven't done the appraisal yet.

Comment: Then my answer should apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're referring to the initial Mortgage Disclosure statement, which contains the Good Faith Estimates for the price of various services and is usually given during the beginning of the application process, then you are not at that point obligated to complete the loan.  You may be on the hook for some fees depending on what else has occurred in the process; for example, if the mortgage company already ordered an appraisal of the property, you're likely going to have to pay for that.  Typically you may be on the hook for around $1000 or so in fees at most at this point, depending on specifics (state, for example).  If you paid some money to lock in your rate, you're likely out that as well, though it would depend on the agreement you signed when you did so.

You're not obligated to complete the loan until you have already completed the loan, by way of signing your HUD-1 and other closing documents.  At any point prior to that you could pull out, though again with some expense depending on where you are in the process.

If you are solely concerned about price, and you're somewhat into the process, I highly recommend talking to your lender and letting them know that you now have found a better price.  They may be able to negotiate somewhat, depending on your credit score, the full appraised value of the property, and other details.  Particularly if the property appraised higher than originally anticipated and/or your credit score came in higher than anticipated, you may well qualify for a better rate than you were initially quoted anyway.